# Updating value which depends on changing of another value, and vice versa

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have this kind of problem. I can't find a solution on web.
I have a value that depends on modification of another value. And vice versa. 
This is my code

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-lg-2 label-margin"> Fondo Bucket 1 (EUR)</label>
            <div class="col-lg-1 right-col-margin">{{::fondo.fnd1}}</div> ---> INPUT
            <label class="col-lg-2 label-margin"> Fondo Bucket 2 (EUR)</label>
            <div class="col-lg-7 right-col-margin">{{::fondo.fnd2}}</div> ---> INPUT
        </div>    
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-lg-2 label-margin"> Fondo Bucket 1 (DIV)</label> 
            <div class="col-lg-1 right-col-margin">{{::fondo.fnd1Div}}</div> ---> INPUT
            <label class="col-lg-2 label-margin"> Fondo Bucket 2 (DIV)</label>
            <div class="col-lg-7 right-col-margin">{{::fondo.fnd2Div}}</div> ---> INPUT
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-lg-2 label-margin"> Bucket DH </label>
            <div class="col-lg-1 right-col-margin">{{::fondo.bktDH}}</div>
            <label class="col-lg-2 label-margin"> Cambio </label>
            <div class="col-lg-7 right-col-margin">{{::fondo.cambio}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My wish would be being able to edit fields `fondo.fnd1`, `fondo.fnd2`, `fondo.fnd1Div` and `fondo.fnd2Div`, but... if I edit `fondo.fnd1` and `fondo.fnd2` the new value of `fondo.fnd1Div` must be the division between `fondo.fnd1` and `fondo.cambio` and the new value of `fondo.fnd2Div` must be the division between `fondo.fnd2` and `fondo.cambio` (I can modify also one of these two fields). Instead, if I modify `fondo.fnd1Div` and `fondo.fnd2Div` the new value of `fondo.fnd1` must be the multiplication between `fondo.fnd1Div` and cambio, and the new value of `fondo.fnd2Div` must be the multiplication of `fondo.fnd2` and cambio. I need an immediate update and avoid a "tragic" loop.
I know that I must use `ng-Change`, but I don't know how use it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: edit what fields?  you don't have any input boxes here, you only have labels, and they are one time bound, at that.  even if you could modify labels, you wouldn't see any update with one time binding.  Please provide a more complete example of what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: You are completely right. The divs containing these four fields: fnd1, fnd2, fnd1Div and fnd2Div, must become inputs. My code is incomplete now.

Comment: I would start with using `ng-keyup` or `ng-blur`.  you want the function to trigger either when the user enters a new value or leaves the field.  Then in the function, change the model value of the other field doing whatever calculation you need.  `ng-keyup` or `ng-blur` won't trigger on the other field during your function, so you aren't going to cause a loop.

Comment: "change the model value of the other field doing whatever calculation you need"  yes, but how? This is my problem, I don't know how I can use ng-change.

Comment: as I already said, don't use `ng-change`.  use `ng-keyup` or `ng-blur` to call a function, and in the function do whatever calculation is required.  for example, `$scope.fondo.fnd1Div = $scope.fondo.fnd1 / $scope.fondo.cambio;`, if this is the calculation you want.

Comment: Thank you very much Claies for yout help. My code now run very well! I have only one question: using ng-keyup or ng-change is exactly the same, but, if I use ng-blur, I must leave the field to notice the updating. Is that the  behavior that we expected? And why using ng-change the code works? Which is the real difference between this one and ng-keyup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different event listeners available in angular.  In particular, there are 4 main listeners that can be used in this scenario, and each operates slightly differently.

**`ng-keyup`**

This event is used when you want to fire your function in response to the user releases a key.  This differs from `ng-keypress`, which fires when the key is pressed, but fires continually if the key is held down.

**`ng-blur`**

This event is used when you want to detect if the focused input on a form is "blurred", or in other words, if focus changes from one input to another.  This will only fire *once* for the entire input interaction.

**`ng-change`**

This event fires whenever a new value is committed to the model.  This will only fire when a change occurs to the model, and will not fire when certain conditions are true, such as the input form value being invalid or `null`.

Note that all of these listeners fire under specific conditions on input fields, and none of them fire due to programmatic changes to the model value.  Therefore, you cannot be stuck in a loop where changing a value causes an event to fire that causes another change.  This was something that could happen with other frameworks, which actually changed the DOM directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your explanation is very useful!